# How to use preg_replace for pattern that have or condition?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

i want to replace part of a string with words that have condition like below:

```
"string1string" => "stringAstring"
"string2string" => "stringBstring"
"string3string" => "stringCstring"
```

and i choose this pattern for first string:

```
/(.*)(1|2|3)(.*)/
```

so i want to replase `1,2,3` with `A,B,C` by `preg_replace()` function.
please help me to do that.

**edit:** first attempt

I use below code for do that

```
preg_replace("/(.*)(1|2|3)(.*)/", "$1$2$3", $string);
```

and the result for "string1string" is :

```
string1string
```

my goal is if `$2` is `1` so replacing with `A` or if `2` replacing with `B` or `3` replacing with `C`

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this yourself? As with most questions on SO if you share your attempt it helps us understand the question and you will get a better response from the community

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: What is the expected result for `"string110string"`? Are you planning to match the first, the last digit, or any chunk of digits and convert them somehow? Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: please check my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead that has callback function in regex match. In callback function, matches stored in array names `$matches`.

Alos `["A", "B", "C"][$matches[2]-1]` convert `1|2|3` to `A|B|C`.

```
$newString = preg_replace_callback("/(.*)(1|2|3)(.*)/", function($matches){
    return $matches[1].["A", "B", "C"][$matches[2]-1].$matches[3];
}, $string);
```

Check result in [demo](https://ideone.com/3gLFrD)

Answer (score 1):

I will summarize your problem. you need replace multiple numbers with multiple characters

If you have array then you should used loop and add below code in the loop & replace `string1string` with your variable

So, you should used `str_replace` with `array`

```
$string = str_replace(array('1', '2', '3'), array('A', 'B', 'C'), 'string1string');
print_r($string);
$string = str_replace(array('1', '2', '3'), array('A', 'B', 'C'), 'string2string');
print_r($string);
$string = str_replace(array('1', '2', '3'), array('A', 'B', 'C'), 'string3string');
print_r($string);
```

[check output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ff684f6e35a505eb8e1fbaaff11033c88ef2910)

Comment: No please check my attempt.